# PyCharm 2018 Python Unresolved Reference 'django' VirtualEnv

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I have the newest PyCharm version (2018) and the latest Django version (2.1) and Python (3.6)

When I want to import something in PyCharm from Django:

```
from django.urls import url
```

I get an error message under django stating:
**Unresolved reference 'django'**

I created a virtual environment and I ran a project on it, the most famous one (polls) and it ran very well.

But now I noticed that I have this error, what is the solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from the Settings > Project Interpreter. (see if it is well set)

Comment: I tried multiple times but every time I want to upload an image i get the following error message: "Failed to upload image; an error occureed at imgur"

Comment: So add link to img

Comment: excuse my ignorance but I am new, how do you do that?

Comment: add here https://imgur.com/upload and give link to me

Comment: thank you :)
here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/kx3MivA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current virtual environment you are using does not have django installed in it. Installing it for the current environment or using a project interpreter which have django installed should resolve the issue.

**1. Installing Django on your current virtual environment via pycharm settings.**

- Go to **Settings > Project > Project Interpreter** and click the
  green plus sign on the right hand side (install option).
- Search for django in the search bar of the available packages dialog
  and select it.
- Select the install package option at the bottom.

**2. Installing Django on your current virtual environment via pycharm terminal.**

- Click on the pycharm terminal and install django using

  ```
  pip install Django
  ```

**3. Changing the current project Interpreter.**

- Go to **Settings > Project > Project Interpreter** and click on the project interpreter drop down menu.
- Choose a project interpreter which have django installed.

Comment: Thank you ^^ I thought installing Django from the PyCharm terminal was the only requirement needed, but after downloading it as a package it all worked out again, thank you for your answer

Comment: @HadiK. pip install in pycharm terminal didn't work for you?

Comment: It didn't before i installed the Django package

Comment: Hmmm. Strange, should've worked. But anyway you have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem specifically with a tutorial that uses an SRC folder. I learned that the SRC folder needs to be marked as a "sources root" in Pycharm. Once done, then the error flagging goes away.
 [Try Django Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW&index=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but none of the answers above and in other posts worked. I use the right interpreter and Django is well installed (in a venv).

I restored default settings with File > Manage IDE settings and this corrected the error.
I suppose the last update of PyCharm went wrong and this restarted everything well.

/!\ As @Vegas precised it in the comment, all configurations will disappear

Comment: Reminder that this will reset PyCharm's settings, so all your configurations will disappear. It boots as if you just installed it.